# PHP - Regex. Replace any space in quote with underscore?

Tags: php, regex

regex noob hear. Via PHP and `preg_replace()`...

I'm trying to make this.

```
id="New York State"
```

Into this.

```
id="New_York_State"
```

But not this.

```
id="New_York_State"_class="United_States"
```

All my attempts have been abysmal!

I've read several tutorials but I am still having a lot of trouble formulating useful patterns with correct syntax.

Please, please, please, include a explanation of the regex pattern with your answer! Also, if you feel up to it, any links to *good* PHP regex tutorials or articles would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your attempts. Maybe you're on the good way.

Comment: Are you doing the replacement in a full HTML document ?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is using DOM, check for all classes and id's and do a space replacement.

Comment: @Baba          I'm doing this within a 7000 line <SVG> document.

Comment: Use `simple_load_xml`?

Comment: Which spaces *exactly*  may be replaced? All spaces within quoted strings but not outside? Only those within `id` attributes?

Comment: Can you add the svg to paste bin ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I would normally go that route. It seems the easiest way to do this but I have been struggling with this for a while... I would be nice to learn how to do it.

Comment: @Baba          Sure.... but to be warned, it's a 19mb file :$

Comment: @Tim Pietzcke   any space within quotes but not outside. Inside id or class properties.

Comment: @Dave Chen     Can you please provide a link for `simple_load_xml`? I did a quick search but all I could find was `simplexml_load_file`.

Comment: haha sorry just citing it off the top of my head

Comment: @DaveChen      (face palm) :P Gonna check out the recommendation, Thanks!

Comment: @Terry just curious: you know that class="United States" has a different meaning than class="United_States"?

Comment: @migg          Yep. The latter is one class. While the first is two classes.

Comment: @Terry well then... just checkin' ;)

Comment: @migg          Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *extremely* **bad** solution:

```
$string = 'blabla id="New_York_State" class="United_States" blabla';

$new_string = preg_replace_callback('#\"([^"]*)\"#', function($m){
    return('"'. str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1]) .'"');
}, $string);
echo $new_string;
```

**Output:**

```
blabla id="New_York_State" class="United_States" blabla
```

---

Allowing only `id=` and `class=` behind the double quotes:

```
$string = 'blabla id="New_York_State" class="United_States" blabla "this won\'t get underscored" yaaaay';

$new_string = preg_replace_callback('#(?<=id=|class=)\"([^"]*)\"#', function($m){
    return('"'. str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1]) .'"');
}, $string);
echo $new_string;
```

**Output:**

`blabla id="New_York_State" class="United_States" blabla "this won't get underscored" yaaaay`

Comment: To tell you the truth I wouldn't know how to do this through the DOM with PHP. Currently I have been loading the `<svg>` into a browser making applicable changes with JavaScript and copying the `<svg>` via firebug to a text editor O_o (eye twitch)

Comment: I'm NOT a programmer. I'm a graphic design student teaching himself to code. I understand most of the regexp pattern, except... `?<=`, and meaning of `*` in `([^"]*)`.

Comment: @Terry I'm a nobody and I learnt from here and there, but don't worry I'll explain :) `(?<=)` is a lookbehind assertion for example `(?<=a)b` this will match `b` if there is `a` before it: `ab` the b here gets matched `acb` the b here doesn't get matched. `*` is basically 0 or more times, `[]` means a character class, so `[^"]` will match anything but `"` we add `*` to it to match several characters if possible `[^"]*`, so for example this will match `abc` in `abc"`.

Comment: You are not a nobody. Don't say that. Thank you for your help, it was a great explanation,

Comment: @Terry haha you're welcome, also you may try [regex101](http://regex101.com/) which is a good site to test your regex and also get a bit of explanation on it and you may take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), have fun !

Comment: I don't want to bother too much but I just wanted to let you know that I think I finally understand how to formulate regex pattens. **Honestly, thank you!** I ended up using two 'preg_replace_callback' functions (awesome function i didn't know about); One for id `'#id=\"[^"]+\"#'`, and one for class `'#class=\"[^"]+\"#'`. By doing so execution time was shaved from ~1.8s down to ~0.2s ^_^

Comment: @Terry Nice improvement, you may drop by in the [PHP chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `SimpleXMLElement`

```
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
$xml = simplexml_load_file('log.svg', "SimpleXMLElement");
recursiveReplace($xml);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

**Function Used**

```
function recursiveReplace(&$xml) {
    foreach($xml as $k => $value) {
        foreach($xml->attributes() as $n => $d) {
            $xml[$n] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $d);
        }
        recursiveReplace($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was waiting for the canonical answer :D

Comment: @Baba          This seems like a very elegant and approachable solution. I'm working on a WAMP environment, it seems that I need to install a few libraries to be able to use the SimpleXMLElement extension. Not a problem but I was really just looking for a regex pattern. Still super usefull, thank you. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `str_replace`.

Your code will be like this:

$id = str_replace(" ", "_", $id); 
or better $id = str_replace("New York State", "New_York_State", $id);

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Actually this information is true, but it doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: This will replace *all*  spaces, not just those within `id` attributes.

Comment: If you use it with the DOM, why not.